# How to round sql query to lower integer

Tags: mysql, sql, select, floating-point, rounding

For example i have a query:

```
select (select size from acc where acc_id = 1)/(select count(m_id) from m_acc  JOIN dns ON dns.dns_id = m_acc.dns_id where acc_id = 1)*1000000;
```

the result of query:

```
3333333333.3330
```

i want to get

```
3333333333
```

i not need round to upper integer. i want round to lower integer. i tried do this:

```
select floor (select size from acc where acc_id = 1)/(select count(m_id) from m_acc  JOIN dns ON dns.dns_id = m_acc.dns_id where acc_id = 1)*1000000;
```

but in a result i received this:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'size from acc where acc_id = 1)/(select coun' at line 1
```

Tell me please, where i have an error ?

Comment: [Floor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor)?

Comment: `floor()` is a function, so you need to put the parameters in brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FLOOR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor). Try this:

```
select FLOOR
(
    (select size from acc where acc_id = 1)
    /
    (select count(m_id) from m_acc  JOIN dns ON dns.dns_id = m_acc.dns_id where acc_id = 1)
    *
    1000000
);
```